# Pandas grouby and flatten based on a column

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a `df` like this:

```
mode id
car 1_2fgg
car 1_2fgg
car 1_2fgg
car 1_2fgg
bike 2_344jd
car 2_344jd
```

I wish to flatten the mode column to get a list of all the unique modes, per `id`, so something like:

```
id modes
1_2fgg car
2_344jd bike,car
```

How could I do this in pandas? I presume groupby id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try join the `unique`

```
df.groupby('id')['mode'].agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique())
```

Or drop duplicates before groupby (might be faster):

```
(df.drop_duplicates(['mode', 'id'])
   .groupby('id')['mode'].agg(','.join)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use [`GroupBy.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html) with [`Series.str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) here.

```
df.groupby('id')['mode'].unique().str.join(',').reset_index()

        id      mode
0   1_2fgg       car
1  2_344jd  bike,car
```